# How i get specific country airport through google apis

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Is it possable to get all airport of given country through google place api or something other.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html)  web service can supply what you require.

If you create an account you can use
this [url](http://api.geonames.org/search?q=london&country=GB&featureCode=AIRP&maxRows=10&username=%2a%2a%2a%2a%2a%2a) for airports near london

Answer (score 0):

You need to use google search control and map

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=yourkey=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('search', '1');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var searcher;

    function OnLoad() {

        var defaultLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(7.885, 80.651);

        var defaultMapOp = {
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: defaultLoc,
            noClear: false
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapDiv'), defaultMapOp);

        var searchControl = new google.search.SearchControl();

        searcher = new google.search.LocalSearch();
        searcher.setCenterPoint(map);

        var options = new google.search.SearcherOptions();
        options.setExpandMode(google.search.SearchControl.EXPAND_MODE_OPEN);

        /*var opAutoComplete = new google.search.DrawOptions();
        opAutoComplete.setAutoComplete(true);*/

        searchControl.addSearcher(searcher, options);
        //searchControl.draw(searcher, opAutoComplete);

        searchControl.setSearchCompleteCallback(searcher, function () {
            var results = searcher.results;

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var result = results[i];
                var markerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(result.lat), parseFloat(result.lng));

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: markerLatLng,
                    title: result.titleNoFormatting
                });
            }

            var center = searcher.resultViewport.center;

            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(center.lat), parseFloat(center.lng)));
        });

        searchControl.draw(document.getElementById('searchDiv'));
    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I need airport names not map. have you any idea about this?

Comment: read [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/) it will help. Anyway I think you need google search control as well